# Drone with Postgres - psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, drone.io

I've tried setting up a drone server using the postgres plugin but I'm completely unable to get it working.

I've done is to copy the default drone setup from the docs:

```
---
  kind: pipeline
  type: docker
  name: default

  steps:
    - name: test
      image: postgres:9-alpine
      commands:
        - sleep 5 #give the service some time to start
        - psql -U postgres -d test

  services:
    - name: database
      image: postgres:9-alpine
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
        POSTGRES_DB: test
```

But I get the following error while trying to start it up

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

My guess is that postgres is not starting for some reason, but it's difficult to tell.

Here is the Postgres log:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default timezone ... UTC
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
sh: locale: not found
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... No usable system locales were found.
Use the option "--debug" to see details.
ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start

waiting for server to start....LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-05-27 08:49:09 UTC
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
 done
server started
CREATE DATABASE


/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

LOG:  received fast shutdown request
LOG:  aborting any active transactions
LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
LOG:  shutting down
waiting for server to shut down....LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-05-27 08:49:11 UTC
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

Either that or Postgres starts up fine but something kills it before other processes have the chance to communicate. I'm not entirely sure though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Then you have to check if the database server process is running. Is `/var/run/postgresql` included in the `unix_socket_directories` parameter of the PostgreSQL server?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe How can i check that/?

Comment: Look into the `postgresql.conf` file, or (as superuser, if you can connect), tun `SHOW unix_socket_directories;`.

Answer (score 2):

Drone brings up services in their own container that have their own hostname.
In your case you named your service `database` so when connecting with `psql` you need to pass the hostname so that `psql` establishes the connection with the container via TCP:

```
psql -U postgres -d test -h database
```